# PHP memcached gives warning 'could not compress value' for values containing special characters

Tags: php, memcached

I have php memcached 2.0.1 and libmemcached 1.0.8.

I have enabled compression. When I try to set some value containing hashes (#), php memcached throws warning

> Memcached::set(): could not compress value

When I remove the hash, problem doesn't occur. This is not happening in php memcache. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: make sure to submit a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

The key must not include control characters or whitespace. Please read this:

https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt#LC41

If that doesnt help, then why cant you apply some encryption logic(for example 'MD5') over the cache key and use it?

Comment: in the application there are thousands of transactions involving these keys. Want to minimize processing